# Test for a difference in an outcome across 2 groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, z-test

I have a dataset of hospital visits across multiple hospitals. One group of hospitals had a special program ‘A’ whereas the other group did not have this program. For each group, I have a percentage of hospital visits that had a ‘good outcome’. I simply want to test whether there is a significant difference in this ‘good outcome’ measure between sites that had program A vs the other sites. I have >300 observations in each group.

I think it is a two sided test of equal proportions (prop.test() in R) that is the right approach, but I’d like some feedback to be sure.

It’s confusing with the various similar tests: chi-squared, Pearson chi-squares, z-test, test of equal or given proportions - are these all the same?

Follow up to this question: Above, I am interested in overall difference, however; I also have the percent of hospital visits that had the good outcome over time (measured every 3 months), I have a feeling it is inappropriate to just do a t.test between the proportions of group A vs group B, would that be correct or why is it inaccurate?
I know I could look into the ARIMA model, but I just wanted to know if there was a difference regardless of time/trends.

Comment: Have you checked whether the assumptions for a difference in proportions test hold for your data? See the assumptions here https://stattrek.com/sampling/difference-in-proportion.aspx

Comment: Yes I have checked the assumptions. I believe they all hold for my data. I have large sample sizes and my two populations are independent. Each group has 70-80% of the positive outcome.

Comment: Are you looking  to test if there is a difference between the special group and the others over time or just at once instance?

Comment: I want to test if the special group had a difference in the positive outcome. So two groups: group A and group B, each has an independent percent of patients visits that had the good outcome. So I want to know if group A was associated with a higher positive outcome.